# Trouble with arrays in Uniform Buffer Objects

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glsl

I am semi-experienced in OpenGL and am currently working on simple lighting for a 2D game. My plan is as follows:

1. Create a Uniform Buffer Object to store two arrays of vec4s representing all active lights in the scene: one for position and one for color.
2. Take in that Uniform Buffer Object as a uniform in my vertex shader (obviously). Transform the data in some way and copy it to an output interface block with the same format as the uniform (sorry if this is confusing/incorrect terminology, don't hesitate to ask for clarification).
3. Use the interface block output by the vertex shader as an input into my fragment shader, and perform lighting calculations using the contents of the block.

This is a simple task, but here's the catch: if the arrays in my uniform buffer are of a size **greater than 14**, my shaders seem to silently fail (no error string from either the compilation or linking process), which strangely makes all other uniforms inaccessible.

The value returned by a call to glGetIntegerv with GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS_ARB as the target returns 4096, which I have taken to mean I should be able to store up to 4096 floats / 4 floats/vec4 / 2 vec4s/light = 512 lights in a single uniform buffer.

Here is the relevant C++ code (note that the float vectors are properly sized to fill a vec4 - I do not believe this is an alignment issue to do with the std140 layout I'm using):

```
    // generate some test light data and upload it to a UBO
    constexpr uint lightCount = 14;
    renderer.GetShader().SetUniform1i("u_LightCount", lightCount);
    struct 
    { 
        float pos[4 * lightCount] = { 0 };
        float color[4 * lightCount] = { 0 };
    } lights;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4 * lightCount; i += 4)
    {
        lights.pos[i + 0] = i * 4;
        lights.pos[i + 1] = i * 4;
        lights.pos[i + 2] = 100.f;
        lights.pos[i + 3] = 1;
        lights.color[i + 0] = 1;
        lights.color[i + 1] = 0;
        lights.color[i + 2] = 0;
        lights.color[i + 3] = 1;
    }
    GLuint ubo = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ubo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(lights), &lights, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
    uint block = glGetUniformBlockIndex(renderer.GetShader().GetId(), "BlockLight");
    GLuint bind = 0;
    glUniformBlockBinding(renderer.GetShader().GetId(), block, bind);
```

I might be doing something weird with binding here. The glBindBufferRange call is required for the shaders work, but I don't see how it's different from the glBindBuffer call.

```
    // update light positions based on scroll wheel and upload to the UBO
    lightDistance = math::clamp(lightDistance + engine.gl->GetMouseScroll().y, 0, 255);
    for (uint i = 0; i < lightCount; i++)
        lights.pos[i * 4 + 2] = lightDistance;
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(lights), &lights, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bind, ubo, 0, sizeof(lights));
```

My vertex shader code:

```
#version 420 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 i_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 i_TexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in float i_TexIndex;

uniform int u_LightCount;
uniform vec2 u_Scale;
uniform vec2 u_Camera;

layout (std140) uniform BlockLight
{
    vec4 pos[14];
    vec4 color[14];
} u_Light;

out vec2 v_TexCoord;
out float v_TexIndex;
out BlockLight
{
    vec4 pos[14];
    vec4 color[14];
} v_Light;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4((i_Position + u_Camera) * u_Scale, 0, 1);
    v_TexCoord = i_TexCoord;
    v_TexIndex = i_TexIndex;

    for(int i = 0; i < u_LightCount; i++)
    {
        v_Light.pos[i] = u_Light.pos[i] + vec4(u_Camera, 0, 1);
        v_Light.color[i] = u_Light.color[i];
    }
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
#define PIXEL_SIZE 5
layout(location = 0) out vec4 o_Color;

uniform int u_LightCount;
uniform int u_TextureFrames[32];
uniform vec2 u_Resolution;
uniform sampler2DArray u_Textures[32];

in float v_TexIndex;
in vec2 v_TexCoord;

in BlockLight
{
    vec4 pos[14];
    vec4 color[14];
} v_Light;

void main()
{
    vec2 fragPos = floor((gl_FragCoord.xy - u_Resolution / 2.0) / PIXEL_SIZE);
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < u_LightCount; i++)
    {
        float x = length(v_Light.pos[i].xy - fragPos) * 2;
        float z = v_Light.pos[i].z;
        float intensity = (x > z ? 0 : clamp((z - sqrt(z * z - (x - z) * (x - z))) / 255, 0, 1));
        lightColor += v_Light.color[i].xyz * intensity;
    }
    lightColor = clamp(lightColor, vec3(0), vec3(1));

    int index = int(v_TexIndex);
    o_Color = vec4(lightColor, 1) * texture(u_Textures[index], vec3(v_TexCoord, u_TextureFrames[index]));
}
```

Intended output (which only happens when <= 14 lights are used):
[intended output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgnGb.png)

Error output (occurs when changing one or more of the array sizes in the shader to a value > 14):
[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVzbT.png)

Is it possible that I've done something wrong and/or skipped something in my OpenGL setup code? Am I using the UBO functions improperly? Is it actually a data padding/formatting error that I've somehow missed? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @robthebloke for figuring this out. The issue was nothing to do with my UBO setup, but rather how I had written my shaders. I was operating on the UBO in the vertex shader, writing the result out to another buffer (because shaders do not have write access to UBOs), then using that resulting buffer in the fragment shader.

However, as Rob pointed out, there is a limit on how many bytes can be sent as input parameters to a fragment shader, accessible via `GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_INPUT_COMPONENTS`. My buffer was exceeding this value, causing the whole pipeline to fail (yet not to throw an error, which I am still annoyed by).

The solution was to defer the operations on the UBO until the fragment shader by passing it the relevant value from the vertex shader as a single `in vec2`. This solved my problem, and I am now able to put as much data into the UBO as I want (up to the limit specified by `GL_MAX_UNIFORM_BLOCK_SIZE`).

Final C++ code:

```
    // generate some test light data and upload to a UBO
    constexpr uint lightCount = 1000;
    renderer.GetShader().SetUniform1i("u_LightCount", lightCount);
    struct 
    { 
        float pos[4 * lightCount] = { 0 };
        float color[4 * lightCount] = { 0 };
    } lights;
    for (uint i = 0; i < 4 * lightCount; i += 4)
    {
        lights.pos[i + 0] = i * 4;
        lights.pos[i + 1] = i * 4;
        lights.pos[i + 2] = 100.f;
        lights.pos[i + 3] = 1;
        lights.color[i + 0] = 1;
        lights.color[i + 1] = 0;
        lights.color[i + 2] = 0;
        lights.color[i + 3] = 1;
    }
    GLuint ubo = 0;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ubo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(lights), &lights, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
    uint block = glGetUniformBlockIndex(renderer.GetShader().GetId(), "BlockLight");
    GLuint bind = 0;
    glUniformBlockBinding(renderer.GetShader().GetId(), block, bind);

    ...
    // inside render loop
    lightDistance = math::clamp(lightDistance + engine.gl->GetMouseScroll().y, 0, 255);
    for (uint i = 0; i < lightCount; i++)
        lights.pos[i * 4 + 2] = lightDistance;
    glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ubo);
    glBufferData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(lights), &lights, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, bind, ubo, 0, sizeof(lights));
    ...
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec2 i_Position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 i_TexCoord;
layout(location = 2) in float i_TexIndex;

uniform vec2 u_Scale;
uniform vec2 u_Camera;

out vec2 v_Camera;
out vec2 v_TexCoord;
out float v_TexIndex;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4((i_Position + u_Camera) * u_Scale, 0, 1);
    v_TexCoord = i_TexCoord;
    v_TexIndex = i_TexIndex;
    v_Camera = u_Camera;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core
#define PIXEL_SIZE 5
layout(location = 0) out vec4 o_Color;

uniform int u_LightCount;
uniform int u_TextureFrames[32];
uniform vec2 u_Resolution;
uniform sampler2DArray u_Textures[32];
layout (std140) uniform BlockLight
{
    vec4 pos[1000];
    vec4 color[1000];
} u_Light;

in float v_TexIndex;
in vec2 v_TexCoord;
in vec2 v_Camera;

void main()
{
    vec2 fragPos = floor((gl_FragCoord.xy - u_Resolution / 2.0) / PIXEL_SIZE);
    vec3 lightColor = vec3(0);

    for(int i = 0; i < u_LightCount; i++)
    {
        float x = length(u_Light.pos[i].xy + v_Camera - fragPos) * 2;
        float z = u_Light.pos[i].z;
        float intensity = (x > z ? 0 : clamp((z - sqrt(z * z - (x - z) * (x - z))) / 255, 0, 1));
        lightColor += u_Light.color[i].xyz * intensity;
    }
    lightColor = clamp(lightColor, vec3(0), vec3(1));

    int index = int(v_TexIndex);
    o_Color = vec4(lightColor, 1) * texture(u_Textures[index], vec3(v_TexCoord, u_TextureFrames[index]));
}
```

Thanks again to @robthebloke for providing a solution and to @Rabbid76 for correcting my misinterpretation of the value `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS_ARB`.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while that I've dealt with this stuff, so I'm sure someone will correct me here, but what does GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_INPUT_COMPONENTS report?

I have a feeling this has nothing to do with your uniform buffer inputs, but might be related to the fragment shader inputs instead? 14 * 2 * 4 == 112, which seems very close to the default limit of 128?

A stupid suggestion would be too split the lights into 2 uniform buffers?

```cpp
// in the vertex shader
layout (std140) uniform BlockLightPos
{
    vec4 pos[15];
} u_Light_Pos;

in BlockLightPos
{
    vec4 pos[15];
} v_Light_pos;
```

because you are only modifying the position here (the colours remain uniform):

```cpp
        v_Light_pos.pos[i] = u_Light_Pos.pos[i] + vec4(u_Camera, 0, 1);
```

So in theory in the fragment shader you'd be able to do:

```cpp
layout (std140) uniform BlockLightColour
{
    vec4 color[15];
} u_Light_Colour;
```

And hopefully stay within the fragment input component limit?

Although now I've just typed that, I realise that u_Camera is also a uniform, so maybe just move the uniforms to the fragment shader instead? (and avoid passing them as fragment inputs?)

```cpp
uniform vec2 u_Camera;

layout (std140) uniform BlockLight
{
    vec4 pos[15];
    vec4 color[15];
} u_Light;
```

Failing that, specify a uniform buffer block in the fragment shader, or even a shader storage buffer?

Comment: Ah. GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_INPUT_COMPONENTS does return 128. It seems then that my approach is faulty, not my UBO setup. I had no idea there was a limit on input variables, although now it seems ridiculous that there wouldn't be.I should be passing the camera itself from the vertex shader to the fragment shader rather than doing the processing in the vertex shader. Changing this fixed my issue, I am now able to use the uniform buffer to its full potential. Thanks a ton!